# Energy Change in a Capacitor by Inserting Dielectric

Tags: electromagnetism, capacitance, dielectric

This is a practice Physics Subject GRE problem.

> A parallel-plate capacitor has plate separation $d$.  The space between the plates is empty.  A battery supplying voltage $V_0$ is connected across the capacitor, resulting in electromagnetic energy $U_0$ stored in the capacitor.  A dielectric, of dielectric constant *k*, is inserted so that it just fills the space between the plates.  If the battery is still connected, what are the electric field $E$ and the energy $U$ stored in the dielectric, in terms of $V_0$ and $U_0$?

I was able to figure out $E$ fairly easily.  Since the voltage stays the same (by virtue of it being connected to a battery), $E = V/d$.  I am having difficult understanding why the answer for $U$ is what it is though.  The answer is $U = k^2U_0$.  What equation(s) would give this result?  I know $W = \frac{1}{2}VQ$, and with $V$ staying the same $Q$ must be the variable being multiplied by $k^2$.  But $Q = CV$ so $C$ should also be increasing as $k^2$ but for a parallel plate capacitor $C$ only increases by a single $k$ when inserting a dielectric.  How to resolve this discrepancy, or what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you've been given is wrong. The energy after inserting the dielectric is $kU_0$

Comment: I see now, I actually was looking at the wrong "correct" answer.  The correct answer is indeed *kUo*.  And that is the correct answer because of what I said above, that *W = 1/2 VQ* and *Q = CV*, so increasing C by a factor *k* increases *W* by a factor *k*.